# Can I restrict a MySQL user to "see" particular tables

Tags: mysql

Can I restrict a MySQL user to see particular tables 
I have several tables 
`(1)database-A table-1`
`(2)database-A table-2`
`(3)database-B table-3`
`...`
Can I only show user `(1)database-A table-1`
let user neither unable to insert nor unable to see other table

Comment: correct：let users neither be able to insert nor be able to see the table

Comment: I suppose you could tuck them away into a separate database. (I think) You could also construct views, and only allow access to those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not table level permissions that can be granted, however there is a complicated way of achieving what you want to do. See this post on the DBA section of stackexchange

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68957/block-user-access-to-certain-tables

You can however revoke all the privileges to a certain table using REVOKE as such:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON table1.* FROM 'user1'@'localhost';
```